# Exchange default ControlTemplate for control

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to modify the `ControlTemplate` for all `AppBarButton` items. Would it be possible to do something like this in `OnLaunched()` or somewhere else?

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton.TemplateProperty = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["DefaultAppBarButtonControlTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ControlTemplate;
```

The code above doesn't work (read only property), but it should demonstrate, what I'm trying to do. Overwriting the complete style does work, but overwriting the `ControlTemplate` only too? I can't use a custom control in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply a style to all controls in your app of the same type, simply create a style without `x:Key` attribute and place it in the `Application.Resources` or in a `ResourceDictionary` that is referenced there.

As a sample, I've taken the default style for `AppBarButton` and changed the place of the label and icon. I did remove all other property setters and only changed the `Template`. XAML style properties are overwritten in the order they are loaded: first the system defaults and then your Application resources, followed by Page/Control resources and inline styles. So since I'm only defining the Template property, all other style properties (e.g. `Foreground`) remain the default system ones.

Sample XAML style of `AppBarButton` to invert text and icon position:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="Root"
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                            Margin="12,0,12,0"
                            Padding="0,5,0,7"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            TextTrimming="Clip"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />

                        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}">
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="TextLabel"
                                Margin="0,0,0,6"
                                FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="Content"
                                Height="20"
                                Margin="0,14,0,4"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

                        </StackPanel>


                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```